# How to find headers of MP3 audio clip?

Tags: java, arrays, audio, byte, mp3

The primary problem I am trying to solve here is to find the length of a MP3 audio clip given in the form of a byte array. In order to find the length, I need to find the number of `frames` in the clip. According to the [MP3 spec](http://mpgedit.org/mpgedit/mpeg_format/mpeghdr.htm), a frame is a byte with 11 consecutive bits set to 1; i.e a byte with a value of 255 and followed by a byte with it's 3 most significant bit set to 1 (decimal value 224). So essentially, once I find a byte value of 255, I am checking if the very next byte is of value 224. But given this criterion, I am not able to find any frame headers in the array. In addition, the referenced doc also mentioned that the next byte after 255 may at times have its 4 MSB set to 1. This way I should be searching for value 240 after 255. Both in either case, I am not able to locate any frame headers. Please advise if I am doing this correctly.

This is my code:

```
public class AudioUtils
{  
    public static int getAudioLength(byte[] audio, AudioFormat audioFormat, int samples, int sampleRate)
    {
        if (!audioFormat.getId().equals(AudioFormat.MP3))
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException(String.format("Audio length computation for audio of format %s is not supported", audioFormat.getFormat()));

        int frames = getNumberOfFrames(audio);
        return ((frames * samples) / sampleRate);
    }

    private static int getNumberOfFrames(byte[] audio)
    {
        int frames = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < audio.length; i++)
        {
            byte b = audio[i];
            int byteInt = b & 0xff; // convert byte to int
            if (byteInt == 255)
            {
                // If there is another byte in the array
                if (i + 1 < audio.length && (audio[i + 1] & 0xff) == 224)
                {
                    // We have found an header. Increment the frames count.
                    frames++;
                }
            }
        }

        return frames;
    }
}
```

Comment: Does the solution by @ **jaket** work for you?

Answer (score 3):

Since sync word is only 11 bits and you don't know the contents of the remaining 5 bits, you need compare only the first 3 bits of the second byte.  A common way to accomplish this is use the binary '&' operator to set the bits you want to ignore to 0 (called masking) and set those same bits to 0 in the constant you are trying to compare with.

In the example below, the second byte is masked with `0xe0` and compared with the same value.

```
for (int i = 0; i < audio.length - 1; i++)
{
    if (audio[i] == 0xff && (audio[i+1] & 0xe0) == 0xe0)
    {
        frames++;
    }
}
```